# ChoosePixelFormat Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to create a simple OpenGL context but the program crashes on ChoosePixelFormat with the error "Unhandled exception at 0x779CE0E6 (ntdll.dll) in OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044." This same code used to work a while back but for some reason doesn't work anymore. I tried updating my graphics drivers to no avail. If it matters, I have a 64-bit Windows 7 Home premium, a GeForce 570 and a Intel Core i7-2600 3,40 GHz.

This is the code I use in the order of execution to the point it crashes:

```
GLEngine gl(WndProc); //WndProc just calls DefWindowProc
- calls ->
GLEngine::GLEngine(WNDPROC wndproc) { //Initialize class

    hRC = NULL;
    hDC = NULL;
    hWnd = NULL;
    fullscreen = false;
    active = false;

    proc = wndproc;
    itemsLength = 0;

    currentActive = this;

    success = true;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int       nCmdShow) {

    gl.CreateGL2Window("Test", 1300, 900, 8, false, true);

- calls ->

bool GLEngine::CreateGL2Window(char* title, int width, int height, bool internalflag) {

    GLuint pixelFormat;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    DWORD dwExStyle;
    DWORD dwStyle;

    RECT windowRect;
    windowRect.left = (long)0;
    windowRect.right = (long)width;
    windowRect.top = (long)0;
    windowRect.bottom = (long)height;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance; //hInstance is NULL here, should it be something else?
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("OpenGL");
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {

        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed To Register The Window Class."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }
    hInstance = wc.hInstance; //hInstance isn't NULL anymore

    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, dwStyle, false, dwExStyle);

    if(!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, _T("OpenGL"), 
        (wchar_t*)title, 
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | dwStyle,
        0, 0,
        windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
        windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL))) {
            DestroyGLWindow();
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Creation Error."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return false;
    }

    if(!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd))) {

        DestroyGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Can't Create A GL Device Context."), _T("ERROR"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd2 = { sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        32,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        32,
        8,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0, 0, 0
    };
    if(!(pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd2)) {
```

GLEngine is in a dll. It shouldn't matter but the information can't hurt.

Comment: Just tested your code, doesn't throw any errors for me (except of a missing `)` in the last if-statement.

Comment: It is a simple null pointer exception.  Probably dies on trying to access the hDC member.  So it *looks* like it called ChoosePixelFormat() but it didn't quite get there yet.  Should be obvious from the stack trace, you'd see CreateGL2Window but not ChoosePixelFormat.  And the debugger, set a breakpoint and inspect `this`.  How `gl` got to be corrupted is hard to see, perhaps you are shadowing it.

Comment: @HansPassant I've put a breakpoint on the ChoosePixelFormat line and it crashes on that line. Also checked that neither hDC or &pfd2 are null. Call stack just shows different dlls greyed out. because I don't have the symbols for them. (ntdll.dll and appinit_dll.dll)

Comment: @BDL What graphics card/drivers do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get address of function with GetProcAddress? Faulty drivers can cause crash on this too. ChoosePixelFormat may be implemented and exported  driver-side, but it might be not exported, then system procedure should be used. exported one may or may not filling descriptor structure, depending on implementation, so you need to call DescribePixelFormat.

Comment: Wouldn't that give an error like "Access violation executing location...."?

Comment: @BDL access violation is typical for driver problem.. but generally it is UB, anything can happen

Comment: @Swift: ChoosePixelFormat is a GDI function, exported from gdi32.dll. A OpenGL ICD should have no business meddling with its entry point.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. If the function pointer address is not loaded correctly, then the error message complains about "Access violation **executing** location", while it states "Access violation **reading** location" when a function tries to access data at an invalid address. And as datenwolf said: ChoosePixelFormat is not a function pointer at all.

Comment: @datenwolf This. I'm actually trying to create the context in order to load the wgl functions. hDC and pfd2 also seem to be valid.

Comment: @Hoxy: may I suggest you try this https://github.com/datenwolf/wglarb for cross checking? If it works with that but not with your code, then we know that it's something in your code we have to fix. Otherwise… I'm looking at you, Team Blue driver developers…

Comment: @datenwolf The same crash happens. I did use the same project on visual studio to test, maybe my environment is somehow screw up. Any suggestions how it could be?

Comment: Never mind that last comment which I deleted. The problem has something to do with another dll I use for vectors and matrices. If I declare a object from that dll even AFTER the call to CreateGL2Window it crashes. Somehow including a file from that dll causes a crash. If I comment out the call to CreateGL2Window, it crashes with the same error message on the declaration.

Comment: @hoxy dll for vectors and matrices? such should overly ineffective, 4x4 and 4d vector operations are practically inline( and can be optimized with sse). Dll calls will be a huge overhead. Why not to use glm or something similar to glm

Comment: @Swift I'm aware it's not very good solution. I just quickly made it because I didn't have a library for them and had the files in another project, it's not supposed to be a lasting solution. I was not aware glm exists, will check on it, thanks!